# How to fit input area to text in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'd like to have an input area to fit text that is inside of it.

My code:

```
<mat-card>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>qwerty</legend>
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>Qwerty Asdf</label>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput disabled="true" name="type" value="qwerty" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Foo Bar</label>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput disabled="false" name="type" value="baz" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>E Makarena</label>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput disabled="false" name="type" value="asdsadsadsadsadsaadsad" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</mat-card>
```

The result of above code is:

[image]

I tried setting width of input to `auto` or `100%` or `fit-content` but that doesn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try directive `matTextareaAutosize` mentioned in https://material.angular.io/components/input/api

That should be exaxtly what you are looking for.

It can not be done using CSS alone, because CSS is not aware of user typing. It has to be done via Javascript.

If you are only interested in "increasing the width" of input field by pure CSS, then you can do it like this:

- make the input field really wide
- set CSS style to underline the typed text (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)
- that should create similar effect to "auto-expand", but it might be inconsistent with Material design

Comment: thanks for your reply, I cannot check it right now, but as far as I remember it allows you to have more rows but the width is kept the same

Comment: yes, I guess so. Wanting to adjust width alone seems unusual for me. I have updated my answer

Comment: I don't want only to expand the area, I want to also shrink it whenever possible

Answer (score 0):

What we did was to create a hidden div with the same value.

Then, we created a directive called `dynamicWidth` that gets the width of any element and adds the width the `[(fluidWidth)]` below.

```
<input dynamicWidth [style.minWidth.px]="inputRef + 25" [style.width.px]="inputRef + 25"  />
```

`value` here is any text or reference. Make sure this is hidden.

```
<div dynamicWidth aria-hidden="true" 
[valueText]="value"
[innerHTML]="value" 
[(fluidWidth)]="inputRef"> </div>
```